# Keep the Smart card resource manager running w/o card reader plugged in

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pcsc

I'm trying to use pcsc-sharp to monitor when card readers are attached/detached. However, when no card readers have been plugged in for exactly 2 minutes, I get the `The Smart card resource manager is not running` error. In the Windows "Services" app, you can also see that the Smart Card service has stopped running.

I've tried the short sample included in the pcsc-sharp sample code (included with the source on GitHub):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {
        var factory = DeviceMonitorFactory.Instance;

        var subscription = factory
            .CreateObservable(SCardScope.System)
            .Subscribe(OnNext, OnError);

        Console.ReadKey();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    private static void OnError(Exception exception) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} ERROR: {exception.Message}");
    }

    private static void OnNext(DeviceMonitorEvent ev) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Event type {ev.GetType()}, (readers: {string.Join(", ", ev.Readers)})");
    }
}
```

Internally, pcsc-sharp uses [SCardEstablishContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379479(v=vs.85).aspx), but MS doc for that function isn't very enlightening.

A quick&dirty solution would be to re-subscribe to the pcsc-sharp's device monitor in the OnError method ...

```
    private static void OnError(Exception exception) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} ERROR: {exception.Message}");
        var factory = DeviceMonitorFactory.Instance;
        var subscription = factory
            .CreateObservable(SCardScope.System)
            .Subscribe(OnNext, OnError);
    }
```

... but is there a cleaner way of keeping the smart card resource manager running?